# How to replace woocommerce editor by classic post editor?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I want to replace the woocommerce editor by classic editor ( as post ).

I tried to install some editor plugin such as TinyMCE but it still not work as I want.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try using Classic Editor plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Answer (score 3):

You can disable block editor for any post type with [`use_block_editor_for_post_type`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/use_block_editor_for_post_type/) filter hook.

```
add_filter ('use_block_editor_for_post_type', 'so57234401_use_block_editor', 10, 2 );
function so57234401_use_block_editor( $use_block_editor, $post_type )
{

    if ( 'product' != $post_type )
        return $use_block_editor;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [Classic Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/) for all my projects. It works for posts, pages, custom post types and products. Also works well with must plugins.

It's a pain to have to install it on every installation but it is the best solution I have found to overwriting Gutenberg.

[nmr](/questions/tagged/nmr) answer is brilliant! In fact it is the most simplistic solution I have seen in a long time. I just tested it and it works like a charm.